# Using curl with PHP to authenticate - mysterious security

Tags: php, security, curl, authentication

I'm trying to make a script that would run through some sites that I visit every day and get the most interesting info/statistics from them. I wanted to use curl for this purpose, because some of these sites require authentification. Everything was ok until I bumped into the site: rossnet.pl which seems to be somehow secured 'cause I can't authenticate myself at all.

The form that I want to use can be found here:
https://www.rossnet.pl/rossnetlogin.aspx

On the left, under the text: "Mam konto w Rossnet.pl - Logowanie". It doesn't seem to have any hidden input fields, only two text fields for credentials, called:
- "dnn$ctr1203$ViewLogin$txtUserLogin"
- "dnn$ctr1203$ViewLogin$txtUserPass"

I'm using the code shown below but the page returned by the server seems as if exactly nothing happened (no error messages, it seems to look the same as when I don't send any POST data).

Does anyone have a clue about what may be wrong? In the code below I put in actual account credentials for you to be able to test the script if you wish to help me.

Here you can see how does the script below work on my server:
http://kremuwa.netii.net/rossman/skrypt.php

```
<?php

$url = "https://www.rossnet.pl/rossnetlogin.aspx";   

$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'dnn$ctr1203$ViewLogin$txtUserLogin=warzywko3000&dnn$ctr1203$ViewLogin$txtUserPass=password123');

$output = curl_exec($ch);  

curl_close($ch);  

echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: I believe cURL is trying to verify the peer's certificate. Try disabling this by adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: Perhaps you have the load the page first (method = GET) and then post the form.

Comment: @njk - unfortunately, I don't think so, because in that case curl should probably return some error message and it doesn't. The second thing is that I had that option set to false before I even posted this question and it didn't make any difference. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jack - could you write somheting more about your concept? Maybe some code or a helpful link? Not necessarily in a comment :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login forms are sometimes protected with challenges that prevent you from directly submitting the form without loading the page first. I've listed a few options that could stand in your way.

One option is cookie challenges, it's also the easiest to deal with by just loading the page (fetch the cookie) and send it along with the form submission.

Another option is a hidden field challenge; a hidden form field is populated with a challenge code and the submission expects that value to be sent as well.

The last option I can think of is an even more difficult approach involving JavaScript; the page would use JavaScript to load the challenge string, maybe obfuscate it a bit and then send it along (via hidden form field or ajax request).